# Vegetation density estimation from distance method: random sampling or along the grid?

Tags: experimental-design, research-design, vegetation

I am planning to sample the tree regeneration (new ones and advance regeneration, > 2m). I am planning to use small circular points to estimate the counts per area (= density of young trees). I wonder about the **sampling design**: what is better for following whole area tree density estimation? If the sites would be placed randomly, some might overlap. Is the sampling across the grid a better option, but requires a set number of subsamples: eg. not very scalable?

For any of the metrics, we will then calculate distances to the closes tree. Is any of the metric better in folliwing density estimation from teh [distance methods](https://learn.landscapetoolbox.org/course/vegetation-measurement-and-monitoring/lessons/6-1-density-overview/#:%7E:text=With%20counting%20methods%2C%20plants%20are,plots%20sampled%20(Figure%205).)?
Or, what I found, [a quadrat sampling](https://www2.nau.edu/lrm22/lessons/quadrat/quadrat.html), combining both aproaches. Seems however quite challenging to do in the field. What are your thoughts? Thank you.

[image]
[image]